# How to get the correct screen width in react-native iOS?

Tags: react-native, width

react-native Dimensions.get("window").width return 375 for an iPhone 6s....
it seems far from correct.

`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions
} from 'react-native';



class AwesomeProject extends Component {

  render() {
    return <Text style={{margin:50}}>Width: {Dimensions.get("window").width}</Text>;
  }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);`
```

[image: clearly wrong, but no one reported this issue in their github, so it seems I did it wrongly....]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

375 is the number of *points* across for the iPhone 6.  For most things, points will be fine.  But if you need pixels, you can use the `PixelRatio` API provided by React Native.

For example, to get the distance across the iPhone in rendered pixels you could use `Dimensions.get('window').width * PixelRatio.get()`, which should return 750 for the iPhone 6.

Comment: @LawrenceCheuk this seem to work great, any chance you can accept this answer? Because this question still appears as open.

Comment: I am using expo and iphone 6S and it says 320*568 (which are not proper values, these are the values of iphone SE). Do you have any idea?