# Why I am getting wrong dimensions on my iphone 6S device via React Native + Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using Expo (38.0.10) and I console.log the dimensions using a real iphone 6S device (both for 'window' and 'screen', they are equal):

320: width, 568: height

I know these are points and not real pixels, but the values are not the proper ones, these are the values of the iPhone SE, for 6S the width should be 375, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39211518/how-to-get-the-correct-screen-width-in-react-native-ios).

How to fix that?

Comment: might be useful to check your Xcode settings

Comment: XCode is not involved in this setup, I am using a real device and Expo.

Comment: hence my advice to check with a simulator and xcode that allows more in-depth debugging.

Answer (score -2):

In Expo, we have the 'Dimensions', that can be used like this: `width: Dimensions.get('screen').width, height: Dimensions.get('screen').height,` that gonna grab the size of your phone and put as a size in the dimension. Remember to import `Dimensions`. I hope I helped you